# Wordpress - Site does not show uploaded images

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a wordpress site about 2/3 years back. 
I may have got the issue because the Wordpress got updated. 
So, we planned to revert to site backup which was taken an year ago using DUPLICATOR plugin.

"I am able to Restore the Duplicator backup. But, the images that were uploaded(wp-content/uploads) are taking Relative path, so , if i inspect the cracked image and add the preceding path, the image is getting displayed".

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if this is related to the TimThumb issue. If it is, update your timthumb.php with the latest version.